# Android recycler view initially always empty

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-livedata

I have a viewmodel like this -

```
private val viewState = SchoolsViewState()

    fun onViewOpened() =
        Transformations.map(schoolUseCase.performAction(SchoolAction.GetList)) {
            when (it) {
                is SchoolResult.Loading -> viewState.copy(loading = true)
                is SchoolResult.ListContent -> viewState.copy(loading = false, listData = it.schoolList)
                is SchoolResult.Error -> viewState.copy(loading = false, error = it.error)
                else -> viewState.copy(loading = false)
            }
        }
```

The viewState class looks like that -

```
data class SchoolsViewState(
    val loading: Boolean = false,
    val schoolList: List<SchoolModel> = emptyList(),
    val error: SchoolResult.ErrorType? = null
)
```

The Fragment view model observe code looks like this -

```
viewModel.onViewOpened().observe(this, Observer {
//Handling the SchoolsViewState here
            swipeContainer.isRefreshing = it.loading

            if (it.schoolList.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                view?.recycler_view?.visibility = View.GONE
                view?.empty_view?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            } else {
                view?.recycler_view?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                view?.empty_view?.visibility = View.GONE
                view?.recycler_view?.adapter = schoolAdapter
                myAdapter.setSchoolList(it.schoolList)
            }
        })
```

The problem is on every swipe refresh I see empty view first and once data is there then i see list of schools. So this is kind of a UI inconvenience. This is due to `viewState.copy(...)` on every refresh gives new state to the UI. How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Could you show what `SwipeRefreshListener` looks like?

Comment: @Anatolii swipe refresh is just an example... The problem occurs when I go to different view and come back to this view where i refresh school list in onResume() without swipe refresh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't show an empty view if your list is empty because the list is still being loaded - that doesn't make sense. Instead, you should show it only if `loading = false` and your list is empty. In this case, you really don't have any other option. Hence, you code could look as follows:

```
viewModel.onViewOpened().observe(this, Observer {
//Handling the SchoolsViewState here
        swipeContainer.isRefreshing = it.loading

        // if means the loading is finished 
        if (!it.loading) {
            if (it.schoolList.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                view?.recycler_view?.visibility = View.GONE
                view?.empty_view?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            } else {
                view?.recycler_view?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                view?.empty_view?.visibility = View.GONE
                view?.recycler_view?.adapter = schoolAdapter
                myAdapter.setSchoolList(it.schoolList)
            }
        } else {
            // here you could show some loading progress or similar
        }
    })
```

Comment: You saved my day thank you :) But do you recommend the architecture what I m using is right with this view state, view model approach?

Comment: @Maria No problem. If my opinion, `loading` is redundant as you could consider your `View` as loading right after your data request has been triggered. Then, once it's complete you could update your `View` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You are updating a different adapter's list than the one that is set as your recyler view´s adapter, see `bookingsAdapter` vs `myAdapter`:

```
view?.recycler_view?.adapter = bookingsAdapter
myAdapter.setSchoolList(it.schoolList)
```

That looks strange to me

Comment: Sorry that was a typo...I have 2 adapters of course but this was a typo. Corrected above. I am using school adapter and still the same issue